# django how can I sort by user field

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

How to make sure that when creating a task, when choosing a category, the user sees only the category created by himself, and not others' together with his own.
There are 2 users. One has a category "user1 category" created, the second has a "user2 category" created. How to make user1 see only the category "user1 category" in the selection field when creating a task for him
The screenshot is attached below.
[selection field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWC4i.png)

Code:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creator", editable=False)
```

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True, verbose_name="category_name")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="category_creator", editable=False)
```

```
class TaskCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = TaskForm
    template_name = 'main/add_task.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(TaskCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tasks.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

I tried to do it with this code, but i couldn't:

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Tasks.objects.filter(category__category__user=self.request.user)
        self.fields['category'].empty_label = "Not selected"

    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ['title', 'category']
```

Comment: What didn't work for the code you tried? Does it give an error or not the result you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Update:

In your `TaskCreateView` add this method:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
    return kwargs
```

Change your forms class to:

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(
            user=user
        )
        self.fields['category'].empty_label = "Not selected"

    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ['title', 'category']
```

Comment: I have updated the answer based on the error you faced.